# GameObjects spawning in wrong location in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the following C# script in Unity:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    int randomIndex= Random.Range(0, sprites.Length);
    Instantiate(sprites[randomIndex], new Vector3(0,0,0), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

In this script I have an array of GameObjects and I want to randomly add them to the scene, for testing purposes I want to create them in the coordinate 0, 0, 0, but after running the game, the objects are created all over the place (seems to be a pattern too) instead of beign created at the origin 0, 0, 0.

I'm taking my firsts steps with Unity so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

---

This is how I'm passing prefabs to the script:

[image]

And this is my script:

```
public GameObject[] planets;

void Start () {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        int randomIndex= Random.Range(0, planets.Length);
        Instantiate(planets[randomIndex], new Vector3(0,0,0), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

That's pretty much all I have in my project.

When running the project, they are created always in the same pattern (0,0,0 is the lower left corner of the purple background):

[image]

Comment: I have literally just asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404299/how-to-instantiate-tiles-based-on-a-2d-array-into-a-platform-game-using-unity

Comment: Your code does not use `i` within the `For` loop. So why loop? Your random range will be incorrect because say sprite has 1 value, it's length is 1, therefore `sprites[0]` is the only element, but your `Random.range` will be `0-->1` giving two choices.

Comment: Please, see my edit, the `for` loop I wrote here was just an example, I edited the code to generate 10 objects, but those ten objects are created all over the place, instead of in 0,0,0

Comment: I can't see anything immediately wrong with your instantiation, but your sprites array, I question, the array should be a set of GameObjects on a list, can you show us how your `sprites` list is build?

Comment: I'm passing the list of objects from the Unity `Inspector` to the script, in the script I created the array like this `public GameObject[] planets;`, then from the inspector I changed the size of the array to 10, then I drag and dropped prefabs to the 10 array slots in the Inspector.

Comment: I can't solve it with the information given, it may be something like the script instantiates as a child element of something else or something like that but that's out the scope of your question so far, can you edit your question and add some screeshots of your Unity Setup and inspector? Cheers

Comment: [Unity Forums](https://forum.unity3d.com/) or [GaveDev SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) may be good places to explore other solutions

Comment: I added a few screenshot of my projects. I already posted a question in the official Unity forum but since it is my first time there a moderator have to review the question first, I have been waiting since a couple of days :/

Comment: @CJ1 Are you doing SetParentTransform Anywhere? because that will translate your coordinates to local.  But chances are you don't even need to instanciate the planets, why aren't you placing them in the scene so they load up instead of instanciating them through a script

Comment: @johnny5 I thought that at first but the screenshot seems to show the Vector3 is different in each instantiation otherwise I'd expect them to stack (in the unintended location),

Comment: @martin, yeah but what if he was setting the planet's parent to be the last planet he added, meaning the children are being instanciated as children of each other shifting the position a bit to the right etc each time

Comment: @CJ1 what is a planet prefab? is it an image, where is the center of the prefab? maybe the center of the prefab is at 0,0 but the planet is actually the child of another game object in the prefab where it's center is off

Comment: I found the problem (I feel like an idiot), the problem was in the sprites, to create the prefabs first I drag and dropped the sprite to the scene, then I created an empy GameObject and dragged the sprite from the scene to the GameObject, I verified that the position of the prefab was 0,0,0 but I didn't verified the possition of the sprite (inside the prefab), this possition was where I first drag and dropped the sprite in the scene to create the prefab, sorry for wasting your time guys!

Comment: Glad you found it. It would be useful to put this as an answer to your own question to explain what was going on `:-)`