# How to instantiate tiles based on a 2D Array into a Platform Game using Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm building a very simple platform game using 2D array to build the map based on it.

There are two simple goals I want and I'm currently not finding the answer:

1. Ensure that the camera is 16:9 and my scene will be 100% displayed in it
2. Build a 2D platform tileset as in an array

My environment:

- **Unity 5.5.0f3 (in 2D Mode)**
- **Camera projection ortographic size 10.9**
- **Game displayed in 16:9**
- **Tileset dimensions are 128x128 px**

Here is my current code:

```
public Camera camera;
public GameObject prefab;

void Start () {
    Vector3 pos = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3 (0, 0, 0));
    Vector3 nextPosition = pos;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < 18; j++)
        {
            GameObject a = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(nextPosition.x, nextPosition.y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            nextPosition = new Vector3(pos.x+(prefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x)*i, pos.y+(prefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.y)*j,0);
        }
    }
}
```

There are 3 things to notice about it:

- I'm using ScreenToWorldPoint to get me the position for 0,0,0
- My building order goes from bottom left to top right, each iteration is put as the past position + block width/height (x and y)
- I'm using a 16:9 for scheme which is 32:18

Using it, this is my result:
[image]

As you can see it stays out of the camera boundary and even tho both camera and code are 16:9, it exceeds 1 column. Also note that the instantiate point is exactly in the middle of my GameObject, so I start instantiating it as half of the gameObject's width and height, meaning:

```
Vector3 pos = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3 (64, 64, 0));
```

And the reuslt is the following:
[image]

Not what I expected at all, by trial and error I figured out it is suposed to be at 16,16:

```
Vector3 pos = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3 (16, 16, 0));
```

[image]
Now its a perfect fit, but it exceeds 1 line at the top and 1,5 columns at the right. Which shouldn't because they are both 16:9

I'm clearly doing something wrong but I can't see what, I've been through this problem in the past but I don't remember what I figured out.

Comment: is your inspector camera view orthographic, as well as the Game camera veiw. The inspector layout looks like the camera view in the inspector is still 3D (perspective).

Comment: Here is my camera inspector: http://prntscr.com/dq44p0

Comment: No, I mean the [viewpoint gizmo](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SceneViewNavigation.html). Click on the square in the centre of the gizmo to swap between Orthographic and Perspective views in the inspector. Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Here: http://prntscr.com/dq471b its 2D with nothing selected under Gizmos

Comment: ahh sorry, I never build in 2D, so wasn't aware that this was hidden. What does your game view look like when running the game?

Comment: The screen filled with blocks, which is what is expected, but its not "Perfect fit", which should be since both code and view are in 16:9, here: http://prntscr.com/dq49he

Comment: It looks to me on that screenshot that the blocks sit in complete tesselation to the edge of the game view window. I think this issue comes down to the inspector pretending to be 2D (for 2D games) but is still infact in 3D mode. It *looks* perfect fit to me. ...

Comment: I would suggest turning off "2D" on your inspector level viewer ( prntscr.com/dq49he ) and then clicking on the gizo as referenced above, this should align things in the *inspector* view but as far as I can tell the game view appears to be as intended.

Comment: (and then turning 2D back on)

Comment: I didn't quite understood your instructions, I've switched between 3D and 2D and opened up gizmos, but didn't saw any pertinent option there, take a look: http://prntscr.com/dq4dwu

Comment: Sorry you misunderstand, the thing in the corner is called a Gizmo, I wasn't refering to the gizmo menu -- I was [refering to this](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/Editor-SceneGizmo.png). Get this to appear and click this box and it will change the inspector camera view to being Perspective or Orthographic, which I *think* will fix you issue.

Comment: If you want to switch projections of the camera (Perspective and Ortographic) you can do that under inspector projection field, in the gizmo view you were refering, I can switch between my camera projection to isometric, anyway the result in perspective with the same code looks like this: http://prntscr.com/dq4gle

Comment: No, not the camera object in the game, I am refering to the camera viewport that you use to view the game level scene view in Unity itself.

Comment: I know, as I told you, I can only switch between perspective and isometric in it, or look in a different angle: http://prntscr.com/dq4obk

Comment: Yes! ok, so does this make a difference with setting the perspective and then turning 2D (scene view title bar) back on?

Comment: Nope, it just makes it 3D and then 2D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**Pos**" needs a shift at the start. It can be achieved using [Bounds.extents](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds-extents.html)

```
    Vector3 pos = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3 (0, 0, 0));

    pos = new Vector3( pos.x + prefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.extents.x,
                      pos.y + prefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.extents.y,
                      0);


    //....the rest is the same as your code
```

This will be better than using the magic numbers (16,16,0). The first tile will be positioned at the left-bottom corner no matter what scale you use.

128x128 px only tells me that you're using a square tile. So it's 128x128 px **but I can fill the whole screen with one tile or I can make it as tiny as I can (thinking in world coordinate)**. The solution is either to scale the tiles or change the **orthognalSize** of the camera.

The easy solution is to change the orthographicSize to fit the tiles.

```
camera.orthographicSize = 18 * prefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.y * 0.5f;
```

**orthographicSize** equals half the height in world coordinate and you need 18 tiles in height.

So all code combined :

```
        Bounds bound = prefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds;

        camera.orthographicSize = 18 * bound.size.y * 0.5f;

        Vector3 pos = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Vector3.zero);
        pos = new Vector3( pos.x + bound.extents.x, pos.y + bound.extents.y, 0);

        //....The rest is the same as your code
```

Comment: You are an angel, i'll give you the bounty with proud! Thank you so much for your assistance also, great answer! It worked like a charm!